# How to use the columns as x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a hard time to create an actually easy plot. I prepared some data as an example I want to plot:

```
m.alphabet_summary <-
structure(c(194L, 185L, 208L, 219L, 194L, 161L, 205L, 219L, 188L, 
227L, 210L, 189L, 196L, 213L, 192L, 207L, 220L, 203L, 181L, 189L, 
221L, 192L, 189L, 205L, 193L, 188L, 187L, 209L, 189L, 227L, 213L, 
200L, 206L, 194L, 187L, 184L, 209L, 223L, 198L, 186L, 183L, 232L, 
191L, 190L, 204L, 209L, 178L, 203L, 184L, 226L), .Dim = c(5L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(c("As", "Bs", "Cs", "Ds", "Os"), NULL))

#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#As  194  161  210  207  221  188  213  184  183   209
#Bs  185  205  189  220  192  187  200  209  232   178
#Cs  208  219  196  203  189  209  206  223  191   203
#Ds  219  188  213  181  205  189  194  198  190   184
#Os  194  227  192  189  193  227  187  186  204   226
```

I would like to have the Y-axis as the values within the cells (values ranging around 200) and the x axis should be the number of the column (ranging 1-10). the grouping/color should be according to the column names (a,b,c,d,o)

thank you so much for any advice!

Comment: If you want to use ggplot, you'll need to make your data a data.frame and rearrange to long form: `library(tidyr) ; library(dplyr) ; library(ggplot2) ; m.alphabet_summary %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(row = seq(n())) %>% gather(letter, value, -row) %>% ggplot(aes(x = row, y = value, colour = letter)) + geom_line()` (or `geom_point`, or `geom_boxplot`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use ggplot, and skip most of your data processing - ggplot will take care of that.

```
sampling <- c("o", "b", "c", "d", "a")
alphabet <- sample(sampling, 10000, replace = TRUE)
group <- factor(rep(1:10, each = 1000))
df <- data.frame(group, alphabet)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, fill = alphabet)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Apart from all the processing to a long data frame that ggplot requires. :-)

Comment: @thelatemail the unedited question started with the data in long form, and then used a set of loops to change the format

Comment: Fair enough then! :-P